# multiple .not() in button not working unless I refresh the page on that specific page

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this ajax website I am working on. I have it so that it will not reload the same page that it

```js
        $('a.ajax-link').not('.active').not('.selected').not('.btn-disabled').on('click', function(e) {
            if ($('#menu-overlay').hasClass("active")){
                CloseAction();
                setTimeout( function(){
                    $(".page-overlay").addClass("from-bottom");
                    $('#main').addClass('hidden');
                } , 3000 );
            }

            else{
                MenuOpen = "0";
                $(".page-overlay").addClass("from-bottom");
                $('#main').addClass('hidden');
            }

        });

       //trigger smooth transition from the actual page to the new one 
       $('body').not('.active').not('.selected').not('.btn-disabled').on('click', '[data-type="page-transition"]', function(event){
                
        if($(this).attr('target') || !AjaxLoad || $(this).attr('href') == '#'){
     return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

    var newPage = $(this).attr('href'),
     oldPage = window.location.pathname.substr(window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
                    selectedPage = $(this).hasClass("selected");

    if(newPage == oldPage){
     return true;
    }
                if(selectedPage == true){
     return true;
    }
                
                if ( MenuOpen == "1" ){
                    CloseAction();
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        // Load new page
                        if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
                        firstLoad = true;
                    } , 3000 );
                }
                else{
                    // Load new page
                    if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
                    firstLoad = true;
                }
                
            });
```

```html
<li>
                    <a id="contact-trigger" class="ajax-link" href="contact.html" data-type="page-transition">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

But when you start at 'index' and head to 'contact', the button does not work the way it should, it still reloads the page and gets stuck, since the ajax will not let it through because it is not suppose to. Now, if I start at 'contact' and click the contact trigger again, it works as it should. So what is wrong, why is it not working the way it should from coming to the specific page?

Comment: Can you include the HTML and all other functions that are being used please?

Comment: Says it is too long

Comment: Please just include the minimal amount of code that we need to be able to replicate the issue you are having.

Comment: <a id="contact-trigger" class="ajax-link" href="contact.html" data-type="page-transition">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x"></i>
                    </a>

Comment: //trigger smooth transition from the actual page to the new one 
            $('body').not('.active','.selected','.btn-disabled').on('click', '[data-type="page-transition"]', function(event){
                
                if($(this).attr('target') || !AjaxLoad || $(this).attr('href') == '#'){
     return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

Comment: @Rmbettencourt add extra info in the question please, not the comments. Code in comments is very hard to read clearly, and also people coming to the question might not see it.

Comment: I do not know how to do that. There is no edit button on the question

Comment: Its at the bottom of your question under the blue tags for jquery and ajax

Comment: Thanks, got it. They should make that button a lot bigger :D

Answer (score 0):

With the code provided, if you don't want the page to refresh on a click function, you need to add preventDefault() & stopPropagation();

```
$('a.ajax-link').not('.active').not('.selected').not('.btn-disabled').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //removes the default click
        e.stopPropagation();
        //Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree
        if ($('#menu-overlay').hasClass("active")){
            CloseAction();
            setTimeout( function(){
                $(".page-overlay").addClass("from-bottom");
                $('#main').addClass('hidden');
            } , 3000 );
        }

        else{
            MenuOpen = "0";
            $(".page-overlay").addClass("from-bottom");
            $('#main').addClass('hidden');
        }

    });
```

Comment: now it does not load the page, well here is the other code that effects the click if it helps. Actually it will not let me post it, says it is too long....

Comment: //trigger smooth transition from the actual page to the new one 
            $('body').not('.active','.selected','.btn-disabled').on('click', '[data-type="page-transition"]', function(event){
                
                if($(this).attr('target') || !AjaxLoad || $(this).attr('href') == '#'){
     return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Than you for the help.......

Had to change the functions and how the work.